# Construct a circle tangent to sides $BC$ and $CD$ and s.t. its meetings with the diagonal $BD$ are tangent points from tangents draw from point $A$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given square $ABCD$

I want to construct (with ruler and compass) the circle in the interior of the square such that it is tangent to sides $BC$ and $CD$ and such that it's meetings with the diagonal $BD$ are tangent points from tangents draw from point $A$:

[image]

It is clear that the center of the circle must lie in $AC$. I tried finding some cyclic quad somewhere and I failed miserably. I then thought about puting $K$ in hyperbola with focii $A$ and the center $O$ of the square. Then again $K$ lies outside the segment $A O .$

This problem is hard because we would think of looking at the locus of the centers of circles such that the meetings of the circle with line $BD$ are the tangents from $A$.

But that this locus is exactly the same as the locus of the centers of the circles tangent to $CD$ and $BC$: line $AC$.

The proof is simple: as the tangents from $A$ must have the same lenght the meetings $M$ and $N$ of $BD$ with the circles must be reflections of each other with respect to the center $O$ of the square $ABCD$ thus the center of the circle must lie in line $AO$ which is line $AC$.

The real geometric constrain is between the distance of the centers (all of which lie on line $AC$) to point $A$ and the radius of the circles.

Let $P$ be in line segment $OC$.

$PA = x$

$r$ the radius of the circle centered at $P$.

$a=AB$

we have that $r^2 = x^2 - x \frac{a\sqrt2}2$ and $x = a\frac{\sqrt2}4 + \sqrt{r^2+\frac{a^2}8}$

and these weird relations are the "locus" that I desire to work with.

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? This information can help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know, duplicating your effort, or using techniques beyond your skill level. ... BTW, if the center of the circle is $K$, then $|AK|/|KC|$ is an interesting value.

Comment: i tried finding some cyclic quad somewhere and I failed miserably. I then thought about puting $K$ in a hyperbola with focii $A$ and the center $O$ of the square. Then again $K$ lies outside the segment $AO$.

Comment: Related issue asked yesterday  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3684324)

Comment: @JeanMarie indeed, thanks for showing me!

Comment: What inspired this? I love constructions like this.

Comment: @HonestAbe I saw the problem in Jean Marie's link posted in another forum and I was like: how can we construct it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let center $O$ of the circle lie on diagonal $\overline{AB}$ with midpoint $M$, and define $a:=|OA|$, $b:=|OB|$. Let the circle meet the other diagonal at $R$, and define $r:=|OR|$; note that $r=b/\sqrt{2}$.

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\underbrace{\frac{|OR|}{|OA|}=\frac{|OM|}{|OR|}}_{\triangle ORA\sim\triangle OMR} &\quad\to\quad \frac{r}{a}=\frac{a-\frac12(a+b)}{r} =\frac{a-b}{2r}\tag{1} \\
&\quad\to\quad a(a-b)=2r^2=b^2 \tag{2} \\[8pt]
&\quad\to\quad \frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{a-b}=\phi \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
(ignoring a negative solution) where $\phi :=  \frac12(1+\sqrt{5})$ is the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

Consequently, the construction reduces to dividing diagonal $\overline{AB}$ in the ratio $\phi:1$. A simple method for doing so is described under "Dividing a line segment by interior division" in [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). $\square$

Comment: thanks, you did find a solution. If nobody comes up with a less algebraic solution I'll accept yours

Comment: hey blue which is the software used for drawing pictures?

Comment: @endgameendgame: I use the desktop version of [GeoGebra "Classic"](http://geogebra.org) to draw my figures.

Comment: oo the pictures are awesome and catchy

Comment: @Blue are you aware of the similar problem asked yesterday [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3684324}) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Your link broke for me; I think you mean [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3684324/409). I noticed it, but hadn't given any thought to the solution. I'd meant to mark this question as "related" to that one; it looks like you've done that, so I don't have to. :)

Comment: @Blue Sorry for the erroneous link :(

Comment: @hellofriends Use "[Dividing a line segment by interior division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Geometry)" to get O. Then create a line L perpendicular to CD and through O. The intersection of L and CD is part of your desired circle.

Comment: yes, I read this answer

Comment: @hellofriends Then I didn't understand your comment suggesting that a "less algebraic solution" would be preferable. Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: I want a solution that doesn't envolve calculating the position of the center. I want a solution that looks for convenient locus where the center belongs from the pure geometric constraints. It can use homothety, inversion, projective results but I don't wanna calculate anything. Otherwise I would do like this answer did and simply calculate everything. The calculations are not the problem.

Comment: @hellofriends This (as described by my first comment) requires no calculations. What step do you want explained?

Comment: how did you figure that the interior division of the diagonal gives us the center of the circle?

Comment: @hellofriends Ah, so you want a synthetic (axiomatic) proof. I thought you didn't understand the construction procedure. Unfortunately, I can't provide that proof. One interesting thing to note is that the point of tangency with the square also divides that side into the golden ratio; therefore, the "interior division" method can also be used on the side instead of the diagonal, and the perpendicular line finds the circle center instead of the point of tangency. Perhaps understanding that will help (it's beyond me currently).

Comment: @hellofriends Ah I see now, my previous observation is just a consequence of intercept theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint: If $K$ is the center of the circle, $O$ is the center of the square and $L$ is the tangency point lying on $BD$ then triangles $KOL$ and $KLA$ are similar. This gives $KO\cdot KA=KL^2$. This allows you to calculate the radius of the circle.

Comment: yes $O$ and $A$ are inverses with respect to the circle

Comment: can you explain further

Comment: @endgameendgame it is just basic circle inversion: $BD$ is the polar line of point $A$ with respect to the circle

Comment: the radius is $\frac{3 - \sqrt5}2$ times the side of the square

Comment: @hellofriends I got exactly the same expression for the radius. The construction of the circle should be straightforward now.